# JDBC Connection - The result set has no current row

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am having trouble running a query on a database. I currently have the following lines in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am connecting using the following code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

    props.load(new FileInputStream(
            "src/main/resources/myprops.properties"));

    String user = props.getProperty("username");
    String password = props.getProperty("password");
    String url = props.getProperty("url");
    String driver = props.getProperty("driver");


    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    String query = "select * from db.ACCOUNT";
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while(rs.next()){

        String name = rs.getString("ID");
    }
```

I have run the query in SQL server and I receive results so I'm not sure why it's not being returned from my code. Additionally, I have run ResultSetMetaData and it returns the column names that are returned from the query (this, to me, means a connection has been successfully made). Why am I receiving the error: The result set has no current row".

As requested, my properties file looks something like this:

```
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url=jdbc:sqlserver://url:port;databaseName=ENV_UAT
username=uname
password=password
```

Thanks

Comment: You are missing a call to `ResultSet.next()` - please read the [Java JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html). This is all documented there.

Comment: The problem is, when I use the while(rs.next()) loop, it never reaches inside the block because there IS NO next. It skips right over it.

Comment: Well that is a different question. Your code does not contain a call to `next()` and also contains no loop that could be entered.

Comment: post your prop file please.

Comment: updated my question to have the next loops @a_horse_with_no_name and added props file